# Unable to load embedded image in mono GTK#

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gtk#

I'm trying to load an image in mono gtk# in Ubuntu.

in csproj file I added

```
<ItemGroup>
 <EmbeddedResource Include="Images/Disable_Tilt_200px.png"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

In code, I added

```
Gdk.Pixbuf  image1 = Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource("Disable_Tilt_200px.png");
```

but when I try to run I get the following error

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: 'Disable_Tilt_200px.png' is not a valid resource name of assembly 'suiModel, Version=1.0.7578.28449, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader.InitFromAssemblyResource (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource, System.Byte[] streamingBuffer) [0x00050] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource, System.Byte[] streamingBuffer) [0x00018] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at Gdk.Pixbuf..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00021] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource (System.String resource) [0x00005] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at MainWindow..ctor () [0x00033] in <1d872bfd9434487a96ebfc391137905b>:0 
  at suiModel.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00007] in <1d872bfd9434487a96ebfc391137905b>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: 'Disable_Tilt_200px.png' is not a valid resource name of assembly 'suiModel, Version=1.0.7578.28449, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader.InitFromAssemblyResource (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource, System.Byte[] streamingBuffer) [0x00050] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource, System.Byte[] streamingBuffer) [0x00018] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at Gdk.PixbufLoader..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00000] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at Gdk.Pixbuf..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resource) [0x00021] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource (System.String resource) [0x00005] in <2f625623313f467f9368802ad38d635d>:0 
  at MainWindow..ctor () [0x00033] in <1d872bfd9434487a96ebfc391137905b>:0 
  at suiModel.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00007] in <1d872bfd9434487a96ebfc391137905b>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake myself.

In csproj file the following needs to be added.

```
<ItemGroup>
     <EmbeddedResource Include="Images/Disable_Tilt_200px.png"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

The file should be referred like

```
Gdk.Pixbuf image1 = Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource("suiModel.Images.Disable_Tilt_200px.png");
```

where "suiModel" is the assembly/Project name.

If we are not sure about the embedded resource name, add the following to the code.

```
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(myAssemblyName);
var resources = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Assembly.Load(assemblyName).GetManifestResourceNames());
Console.WriteLine("List of Manifest Resource Names");
Console.WriteLine("resources");
```

This will print all embedded resources.